# Sum of Exponential RVs Convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

> Is the following true for exponential independent random variables $X_i$ with CDF $\mathbb{P}\left( X_i \leq x\right)=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}e^{- \frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}}$?
>   $$ \lim_{t \to \infty} \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\sqrt{t}/2} X_i \leq t\right)=1$$

Since $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=\sqrt{t}$ that goes to infinity as $t \to \infty$, we cannot use the weak law of large numbers, central limit theorem, or the Chebyshev inequality. Any other idea?

Comment: Hint: Use the (weak) LLN on the standard exponential $Y_i=X_i/\sqrt{t}$.

Comment: @Did Great! I want to learn how you realized it.

Comment: Is the sum upto $\lfloor\sqrt{t}/2\rfloor$?

Comment: @Gordon  Yes, that is true.

Comment: The CDF is more likely to be $\mathbb{P}\left( X_i \leq x\right)=1-e^{- \frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}}$ so that it tends to $1$ as $x$ increases without limit